# Arduino UNO web client with HLK-RM04. [Request a Web page]

Tags: networking, arduino, wifi, webrequest, arduino-uno

I have being trying to connect my Arduino UNO to the internet using the HLK-RM04 modulo.

I connected to the HLK-RM04 in server mode, the Arduino answered me good but now I want to access to the internet (to an access point), a host with a specific ip or whatever but connect and send information to a webpage.

```
+----------+          +-------------+           +---------------------------------+
| Arduino  |  ------> |  HLK-RM04   |  -------> +   internet: http://google.com   |
+----------+          +-------------+           +---------------------------------+
```

I tried sending over serial por from the arduino to the HLK-RM04 this request:

The HLK-RM04 connected to a access point.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
```

But nothing happens.

1. Am I doing right sending this request?
2. How can I access to internet with Arduino using HLK-RM04?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consideration to use HLK-RM04.

1. Have clear the concept of HTTP request (Headers and Body in Raw
   Format).
2. Configure the time out of your HLK-RM04.

Send information (HTTP Request) through SerialPort at the same BaudRate of the HLK-RM04.

Good luck.